# Which are the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .NET Framework dependencies?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, installation

I'm trying to install SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET framework on a fresh new Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 virtual machine. The installation stops with this error:

> Error 1904. Module C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\crtslv.dll failed to register. HRESULT -2147024770. Contact your support personnel.

I have installed different versions of Microsoft C++ Redistributable and still have the error. Searching on Internet and SAP forums, it says that there's some missing dependencies, but nowhere shows which are the dependencies. What am I missing? Which are the dependencies I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was installing the latest version (13.0.21) of SAP Crystal Reports runtime for .NET. So it turns to be that I needed **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistrributable** for the SP 21.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error "crtslv.dll failed to register. HRESULT -2147024770". Try to install **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistrributable** (x86 or x64 depending upon your OS). 
Sometime even "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistrributable" won't install properly if **your OS is not updated**. (Please update your Os using windows update settings)

Answer (score 0):

Update windows KB2999226 before install Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET, it works for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

SAP Crystal Reports Runtime 13.0.21 and above requires:

1. Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 or above.

   - SP1 x86 and x64 can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=5842), you need to download and install only: windows6.1-KB976932-X64 or windows6.1-KB976932-X86.
2. Microsoft Windows Update KB2999226 (require Service Pack 1)

   - Download x86 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49077)
   - Download x64 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093)
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (require Service Pack 1)

   - Download x86 and x64 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Install all of the dependencies and you will get rid of the "failed to register .dll".

More info:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads