# how to solve error 1904 in crystal report runtime installation

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm installing Crystal Reports Runtime 13.0.22 for my application that has to create some reports but while installing CRforVS 13.0.22 it shows the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is a Windows error code that could be due to insufficient permissions.  Do you have Administrator user permissions on the computer?  If not, then you will need to contact someone who does and have them install this for you.  If you are, you may simply need to right click the EXE file and choose "Run as Administrator" when trying to install this.

If you don't believe this is a permissions problem, then you could also have a conflicting version of Crystal Reports assemblies already installed.  Click Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features and then search for any installed versions of Crystal Reports and uninstall them, then try installing your CR Runtime client again.

Comment: any other suggestions

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to verify you have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package and all of your .NET frameworks installed.  These problems usually throw more specific errors, but the error your are getting is possible if one is missing according to SAP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to install SAP Crystal Reports Runtime SP21 or above in Windows 7.
For that you need to install the dependencies:

1- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package.

2- Microsoft Windows Update KB2999226.

Both require Windows Service Pack 1.

I was getting the same error. 
I installed the dependencies above and it solved for me.

More info:

[Which are the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .NET Framework dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286649/which-are-the-sap-crystal-reports-runtime-engine-for-net-framework-dependencies/61689373#61689373)

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Answer (score 0):

Just had this error in SP32.

Install the runtime first, then the visual studio installer.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the older versions solved this problem. Also, install Visual c++ runtime 2013 for SP33