# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio installation error 1904

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Somehow my long-time running install of CR for Visual Studio 2013 Professional stopped working. I could not open any .rpt files.  I tried in VS2017 and VS2010...same thing.  So...

Trying to install/update to the latest Crystal Reports for VS 13-0-23.exe, downloaded from the SAP website.  Running as Administrator, I get errors 1904, which seems to be issues with Framework 4.0.

```
Error 1904. Module C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Report for .NetFramework4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\craxddrt.dll failed to register. Result -2147023898. Contact yourself!
```

Progress update Monday: I seemed to have been able to reinstall Framework 4.0. Then, Installing CR again, I pressed "Ignore" on each of the 6 failed to register errors.

Then, trying to manually register these dlls using RegSvr32, I get errors:

```
The moddule 'craxddrt.dll' failed to load.
Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug
it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.  
Invalid access to memory location.
```

and VLE.dll register complained:
    The module 'vle' may not be compatible with the version of Windows that you are running.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional, so???

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked.  I finally removed and resinstalled Visual Studio 2013 and the Crystal Report engine for Visual Studio.  Two days later I'm back to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Crystal Reports SP21 or above you need meet some dependencies in Windows 7:

1- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package.

2- Microsoft Windows Update KB2999226.

Both require Windows Service Pack 1.

The links below are about installing the Crystal Reports Runtime SP21+, but apply:

[Which are the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .NET Framework dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286649/which-are-the-sap-crystal-reports-runtime-engine-for-net-framework-dependencies/61689373#61689373)

[how to solve error 1904 in crystal report runtime installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495134/how-to-solve-error-1904-in-crystal-report-runtime-installation/61689461#61689461)

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads